# How to publish a .NET MAUI Application for Windows ARM64 from a DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, maui

I'm attempting to publish a .NET MAUI application for Windows/ARM64 from a DevOps pipeline. I can successfully create the app package from the command line using the following command:

`dotnet publish MyProject.csproj --no-restore -c Release -f net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0 -r win10-arm64 --sc true -p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=true -p:PackageCertificateThumbprint=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

However, when I attempt to issue the same command in my Azure DevOps pipeline, I get the following error:

```
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe publish D:\a\1\s\***\***\***.csproj --no-restore --nologo -c Release -f net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0 -r win10-arm64 --sc true -p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=true -p:PackageCertificateThumbprint=7582CEF5BD6AD2B9EAA88FDC9257859556AA2CEC
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\7.0.306\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(266,5): error NETSDK1047: Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\***\***\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0/win10-arm64'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include 'win10-arm64' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers. [D:\a\1\s\***\***\***.csproj::TargetFramework=net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0]
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
```

This is the relevant step from my pipeline:

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Publish Windows ARM64'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: **/*.csproj
    arguments: '--no-restore --nologo -c Release -f net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0 -r win10-arm64 --sc true -p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=true -p:PackageCertificateThumbprint=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

And these are the relevant property groups from my project file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0|AnyCPU'">
    <TrimMode>copyused</TrimMode>
    <MtouchDebug>True</MtouchDebug>
    <ApplicationTitle>My App</ApplicationTitle>
    <ApplicationId>com.company.myapp</ApplicationId>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0|ARM64'">
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <TrimMode>copyused</TrimMode>
    <MtouchDebug>True</MtouchDebug>
    <ApplicationTitle>My App</ApplicationTitle>
    <ApplicationId>com.company.myapp</ApplicationId>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0|AnyCPU'">
    <TrimMode>copyused</TrimMode>
    <MtouchDebug>True</MtouchDebug>
    <ApplicationTitle>My App</ApplicationTitle>
    <ApplicationId>com.company.myapp</ApplicationId>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0|ARM64'">
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <TrimMode>copyused</TrimMode>
    <MtouchDebug>True</MtouchDebug>
    <ApplicationTitle>My App</ApplicationTitle>
    <ApplicationId>com.company.myapp</ApplicationId>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I thought that MSBuild was picking up the wrong property group and the the runtime identifier wasn't be set, so I added a new property group that included a variable I could set on the command line. I was hoping I could coerce MSBuild to use the property group that I wanted:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Build_ARM)'=='Release|net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0|True'">
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <TrimMode>copyused</TrimMode>
    <MtouchDebug>True</MtouchDebug>
    <ApplicationTitle>My App</ApplicationTitle>
    <ApplicationId>com.company.myapp</ApplicationId>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I set the property in the DevOps step:

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Publish Windows ARM64'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: **/*.csproj
    arguments: '--no-restore --nologo -c $(BuildConfiguration) -f net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0 -r win10-arm64 --sc true -p:Build_ARM=True -p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=true -p:PackageCertificateThumbprint=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

This gives me the same error message I mentioned above. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or how to convince my DevOps pipeline to build my app for Windows/ARM64.